# Weighted sample mean and variance - asking for references and details

Tags: variance, references, weighted-mean, mean, weighted-data

I found this wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Accounting_for_correlations) which tells how to compute the weights to get a BLUE for the mean from correlated observation, assuming the correlation is known.

What I'm asking is:

1. Some references (books) where to study this topic with a greater detail, but preferably not too abstract textbooks, I'm neither a statistician nor a mathematician.
2. Do the weights in the [previous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Accounting_for_correlations) reference also minimize the variance of the (weighted) sample variance? I.e. is a proper weighted sample variance a "best" estimator for the variance?
3. Is it wrong (i.e. biased) to evaluate the sample variance without proper weights, just considering the weighted mean instead of the "unweighted" one in the computations?

Comment: Re (1), a couple hundred hits on a search of this site for [variance weighted mean](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+weighted+mean) might be a good start!